# How do delete songs for StepMania 5 on Windows?

Tags: stepmania

I am relatively new to StepMania. I recently downloaded a ton of songs. Now, I want to delete a pack. When I look in `%appdata%/StepMania 5/Songs`, there are **no** songs, even though I remember putting songs into this folder.

Searching my computer reveals that there are files in `%appdata%/StepMania 5/Cache` for each song. However, deleting the cache doesn't remove any packs from StepMania. (The songs still appear ingame, and the cache folder will regenerate every time you launch the game)

How do I delete a pack in StepMania if the `Songs` folder is already empty?

Comment: This is not technical issues

Comment: The caches will have nothing to do with your actual song data. You need to look at the configs to see where it's pulling the songs from. It's been a long time since I last installed/used SM but those settings are there. Also, appdata is probably not a reliable source for game content, that usually holds user data. Check the actual install folder of the game. If all else fails, just look for large files within your install folder (~5-10MB+). There's a good chance it's a set of song files.